# Adding a column to an existing list and filling it with data

Tags: 2013, custom-list

I have a list with data

**Title Num**

Item1 123

Item2 456

Now I have more data I need to add in a form of a third column and append it to the existing items

**Title Num Money**

Item1 123 $12

Item2 456 $15

Obviously this can be easily done manually however my list is rather large and I was wondering if there is a way to take something such as an excel column and add it to the list. I cant recreate the list as some items have in progress workflows.

Answer (score 0):

Use the quick edit function on the Items tabs. If there's a particular value you'll use over and over you can set it as the default when you set up the column. Quick edit also allows you to copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Multiple ways, try one of the following:

1. You can Edit the List using Quick Edit Mode. For Fast Editing for large lists.
2. If you know how to code, you can use bulk updating using REST/JSOM.
3. If you are having Microsoft Access installed on your machine, you can open the List using "Open with Access" option under "LIST" option in top ribbon and quickly update your list.

Comment: does this answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

The best is to recreate the excel with changes and import it in import spreadsheet type list since you are saying  that data is very very large .

While selecting an app ,select import spreadsheet type of app .Name your app.

Then in the file location click on browse . Choose your excel file to be imported  A pop up will open .

In the "range type" drop-down select option "range of cells".

Then once click on the select range option . You will see that a range gets selected in your excel .Drag and select the entire range of cells in the excel and click on import .

All your excel data will get imported in the excel.

Let me know if this does not help.

Comment: Tomasz don't want to create new list, he wants to add new column and data for that column.